# Is there a "big open cell" analogue for parabolic subgroups?

Tags: algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a $p$-adic field.  Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$ containing a minimal parabolic $P_0$.  Let $S$ be a maximal split torus of $P_0$, and let $\Delta$ be a set of simple roots of $S$ corresponding to $P_0$, with $\theta \subseteq \Delta$ corresponding to $P$.

There is a unique $w$ in the Weyl group $W = N(S)/Z(S)$ such that $w$ maps $\theta$ into $\Delta$, and sends $\Delta - \theta$ to negative roots.  Is the double coset $PwP$ always open in $G$?

Consider the special case where $G$ is quasisplit and $P = P_0$ is a Borel subgroup. In that case, $\theta = \emptyset$, and the $w$ described above is just the long element, in which case $PwP$ is open as the "big cell."

Comment: Sure, over any field $k$, via the "dynamic approach" to describing parabolic $k$-subgroups. Pick a 1-parameter  $k$-subgroup $\lambda:\mathbf{G}_m\to P$ such that $P=P_G(\lambda)$, so $P=L \ltimes U$ for the smooth connected unipotent $U:=U_G(\lambda)$ and connected reductive $L:=Z_G(\lambda)$, so $U=\mathscr{R}_u(P)$ is the unipotent radical and $L$ is a Levi $k$-subgroup. The crucial point is that for $U^{-}:=U_G(-\lambda)$ the multiplication map $U^{-}\times L\times U=U^{-}\times P\to G$ is an open immersion. See section 2.1 of the book *Pseudo-reductive Groups* for a much wider context.

Comment: @nfdc23, I have converted your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294974/is-there-a-big-open-cell-analogue-for-parabolic-subgroups/427424#comment732290_294974) to an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/427424) so that this question can be marked as answered (rather than just leaving a comment suggesting you do so, since I think you haven't been active on MO for a while).  If you would like to leave the answer yourself, then please let me know so that I can delete mine.

Answer (score 2):

@nfdc23 answered this question in [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294974/is-there-a-big-open-cell-analogue-for-parabolic-subgroups#comment732290_294974).  Here is their comment as an answer, made CW to avoid reputation:

> Sure, over any field $k$, via the "dynamic approach" to describing parabolic $k$-subgroups. Pick a 1-parameter  $k$-subgroup $\lambda:\mathbf{G}_m\to P$ such that $P=P_G(\lambda)$, so $P=L \ltimes U$ for the smooth connected unipotent $U:=U_G(\lambda)$ and connected reductive $L:=Z_G(\lambda)$, so $U=\mathscr{R}_u(P)$ is the unipotent radical and $L$ is a Levi $k$-subgroup. The crucial point is that for $U^{-}:=U_G(-\lambda)$ the multiplication map $U^{-}\times L\times U=U^{-}\times P\to G$ is an open immersion. See section 2.1 of the book [*Pseudo-reductive Groups*](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316092439) [by Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad] for a much wider context.